# Unable to generate a report with SAP Crystal report

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am facing one issue with Crystal reports that I am using to generate a report for my orders in WPF application.

My work station configuration is Windows 7 (Ultimate) 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010.

I have not installed any of the Crystal Report engines but I have copied all the necessary dll's to my project (Created a folder and then referenced in my project).

But when I click the button (button which generates a report), I am getting an exception in the report constructor (different exceptions are coming for different run's).

The main exception says

> "The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception."

When I dig into inner exceptions, I got to know this.

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer,
>   Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"

Here is the screen shot of my error,

I have googled it and got to know that I need to install CR for Vstudio 2010, but if I install my development machine, how can I make an installer to deploy in client machine and I don't want to install the CR in all machines (Where I going to deploy to many of my customer's).

I really need an help in solving this, what can I do for this to resolve my issue?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You're planning to use Crystal Reports reporting engine, but don't want to deploy it? Is it so?

Comment: I really did n't get your question @Dennis, what I want to do is to generate a report. And I can't install the CR for all of my client's machine (because I have many clients and installing is really problem for me). But I can copy all necessary dll's into my application which is going for deployment.

Comment: Noah @TheodosiusVonRichthofen I have made a bootstrap package to install along with windows installer, but no luck. So, I did another way to make my work progress, but still searching for the solution that works for me.

Comment: I told my client that this is a Prerequisite for the application to generate report and I have given CR for VS13 setup file separately and asked them to install in all the machines. This is way, I come up with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a ClickOnce installation for your application?  If so, you can specify SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework as a prerequisite under the project's Publish... properties, so it will install anytime your app installs, it will download and install from the web.  If not ClickOnce, your installation method can be configured to install the engine with your app as well.  To develop, you need to install CR for Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using Windows installer to deploy my application. Is there is any way that I can make a package of those required dll's in my deployment package so that they can simple install without accessing internet.

Comment: Haven't used a Windows installer for a while, but I know i have done it before.  Pretty sure you just pick it in the prerequisites.  This should get you started:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Okay, so in order to generate a report, I have to install the CR for 32 or 64bit, otherwise I can't use it. This is what you mean to say. Does adding all necessary dll's is n't sufficient to generate a report?

Comment: I believe for your development machine Crystal requires you to install Crystal for Visual Studio.  This will then allow you to include the References in your project, so it can work on your dev machine.  For deployment, yes, you must include the prerequisite for Crystal, whether that be 32 or 64 bit.  Here's some more links (not sure what versions of Crystal/Visual Studio you are using etc.): http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824  http://scn.sap.com/people/coy.yonce/blog/2010/11/12/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-production-release-now-available

Comment: One of my dev installed the CR and she was able to generate the report. So she has checked in all her code with all necessary dll's and the same I am using (after taking the latest from TFS). But still no luck. I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 (64bit - Ultimate).

Comment: are you saying the deployed app won't run a crystal report or your development machine won't run it in debug?  You MUST install Crystal Reports for Visual Studio first on your dev machine.  If its the deployed app, did you include the SAME versions etc. for prerequsities?

Comment: also if you are sure you have done the above, try creating and using a blank report.  the report itself may be the issue due to permissions/access/etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62427/discussion-between-ganesh-and-theodosius-von-richthofen).

Answer (score 3):

Official documentation [says](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Deploying+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Runtime):

> Deploying Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 (CRVS2010) runtime
>   files is mandatory in order to ensure that a project containing
>   Crystal Reports components functions correctly.

Either follow these recommendations, or refuse Crystal Reports usage in your application and choose another reporting engine, which deployment fits your requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to install app that uses CR without administrator rights?

Comment: +1 : Thats what I would have thought. Installing is different then copying Dlls. there are registry keys and other background crap that are changed when you install.

Comment: @VDohnal: as it stated, CR uses msi/msp packages, i.e., Windows Installer. Hence, there's nothing special about security. I'm not a sysadmin, but I think, that it isn't good practice to allow non-privileged user to install software.

Comment: Click once applications (or simple .net exe) can usually be installed in user profile without any administrative rights by simple copying - I find it great. It is a pitty that CR does not offer non msi solution, it makes it less deployable.